# How can you extend a Symfony2 service defined with the JMS Di Extra @Service annotation?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Say I have a FormType in a re-usable bundle like so:

```
/**
 * @Service("acme_core_purchase.form.add_to_basket")
 * @FormType
 */
class AddToBasketType extends AbstractType
{}
```

In my controller I inject it, to do whatever I need:

```
/** @Inject("acme_core_purchase.form.add_to_basket") */
protected $add_to_basket_form;
```

Say in a particular project I want to extend that form and add some extra fields in, how am I meant to do this with annotations?

```
class AddToBasketType extends BaseAddToBasketType
{}
```

- I can't just create a form with the same service name, that doesn't
  work / make sense- the assignment doesn't follow the priority set in
  AppKernel::registerBundles as far as I can tell. I suspect this is
  conceptually flawed anyway.
- I can change the service name, but then I need to inject a different
  service everywhere I've used it, which involves extending all of
  those things.
- I can store the service name in a parameter then inject that
  everywhere instead, that way I can have the correct service name
  injected everywhere, but I'd also need to inject the container to be
  able to retrieve the service.
- I've been doing the latter wherever I've needed to, but surely there
  is a better way? Or at least, there should be.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use the Form component own inheritance.

```
/**
 * @Service("acme_core_purchase.form.add_to_basket")
 * @FormType
 */
class AddToBasketType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName() { return 'add_to_basket'; }
    public function getParent() { return 'form'; }
}

/**
 * @Service("whatever")
 * @FormType
 */
class AddToBasket2Type extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName() { return 'add_to_basket2'; }
    public function getParent() { return 'add_to_basket'; }
}
```

Comment: How do I go about instantiating the form in my controller if doing it this way? Also, perhaps forms were a bad example, the same question applies to generic services too.

Comment: @Steve, you should be able to specify `parent="service.id"` in the `@Service` annotation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the service piece of their [annotation configs](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations#service)

Notice the `parent="another.service.id"`

```
<?php

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service("some.service.id", parent="another.service.id", public=false)
 */
class Listener
{
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this functionality, but it requires a different service be injected into the controller. Breaking points 2 and 3 in the list in my question.